# FSM in a graphical function

Tags: stateflow

Is it possible to put a state inside a graphical function?
We know that we can make graphical functions in matlab.
Can we build a FSM in a graphical function?
Can we put states in graphical functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's impossible to include a state directly into a grahical function.

My ideas:

1. You build your own statechart in action language without any stateflow states.
2. Check your design :-)
3. This workaround should work: Stateflowchart -> grahical function -> simulink function -> stateflow block. 
   But be aware of the corect block triggering.